# Matplotlib / must install version 1.4.3 / Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, matplotlib, virtual-machine

I received a python script from an archive from a former employee.  It states that I need:

- python 2.7
- numpy 1.92
- scipy 0.15.1
- scikit-image 0.11.3
- scikit-learn 0.16.1
- tifffile 0.5
- pandas 0.16.2
- matplotlib 1.4.3
- pylab 1.9.2

I built an UbuntuMATE virtual machine.  This comes with python2.7.15.  I then moved on to installing the packages using `pip`.  This went pretty well up to the point where
`matplotlib 1.4.3` had a bad "egg". Word on the street was that it was a bad install. I then installed `matplotlib 1.5.3`.

But I couldn't install `pylab`.  (Could not find version...)

Advice was that with sufficient `matplotlib` and `scipy`, I shouldn't need `pylab`.

I ran the old python script and got lots of errors with `matplotlibrc`.

As an alternative I tried to install `matplotlib 2.0.0`.  This results in still more complaints from `pip`, including:  unsupport LaTEX, deprecated functions.

Is there a way out of this mess?

Why *might* my former colleague have indicated `pylab 1.9.2` if it cannot be installed?

Why is `matplotlib 1.4.3` uninstallable?

Should I wipe out my VM and start over or can I salvage the installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pylab is part of matplotlib. It is essentially a [small file](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pylab.py) that makes numpy, matplotlib.pyplot and some matplotlib.cbook and matplotlib.dates functions available under the same namespace.

You cannot install pylab on its own. And there is no pylab-version.

You might notice though that the list you got states `numpy 1.92` and `pylab 1.9.2`. Since (a) There hasn't ever been a version 1.92 of numpy, and (b) there hasn't ever been a version 1.9.2 of matplotlib, what this probably means is

```
numpy 1.9.2
```

There are no details given as to why the installation fails. Therefore just note that I was able to install all versions, except `tifffile`, perfectly fine via conda(-forge)

```
>conda create -n sometest python=2.7 numpy=1.9.2 scipy=0.15.1 scikit-image=0.11.3 scikit-learn=0.16.1 pandas=0.16.2 matplotlib=1.4.3
```